# Is there any regular expression in python to find out the space in folder path

Tags: python, regex

I have a python strings as below:

```
mystring1 = "command1 "  "D:\\The palace\\The King\\ " "D:\\The palace\\The Queen\\"

mystring2 = "command2 "  "D:\\Thepalace\\TheKing\\ " "D:\\Thepalace\\TheQueen\\"
```

Is there any regular expression by which we can find out whether a space exists in the folder path

ie how can i distinguish `mystring1` to `mystring2` by using a regular expression

Comment: Those don't appear to be valid python strings, did you mean `mystring1="command1 D:\The place\The King\ D:\The place\The Queen\"` or perhaps `mystring1='"command1 "D:\The place\The King\" "D:\The place\The Queen\"'`

Comment: ...see you edited it, but still not valid strings.  We should be able to copy and paste these code snippets into a python prompt, and not get a syntax error.  Fix them.

Comment: You don't need a regex.  A simple equality check will fail (after you properly escape the backslashes).

Comment: "Is there any regular expression by which we can find out whether a space exists in the folder path." Sure... \S* matches any non-whitespace character. If there is a space, it won't match.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that `mystring1` and `mystring2` will be proper Python strings, I think you want to take a look at the [shlex](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/shlex.html) Python package. It's specifically created for parsing such strings. Then you can use `shlex.get_token()` to retrieve the command, and the arguments to the command, quotes/spaced parsed and all.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need regular expression indeed. A simple string method `string.find(string)` would do.

```
s = "some string"
space = " "
s.find(space) # gives -1 when space is not in s, otherwise the offset of its 1st appearance
```

**EDITED:**

This answer is edited according to the edition of the question.

Since you're on Windows, I present you `":\\. .*\\"` for commands with absolute paths. And as for relative paths, I'm afraid there won't be a nice solution to detect.

Comment: This will not work if the string contains multiple paths as suggested by the question. See my answer for a more complete solution.

Comment: @mutzmatron Yes that's true, and I've made an edition. Actually when I gave that answer, the strings given by him were invalid for Python. So forgive me, dude.

Comment: Your addition still doesn't solve the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you meant

```
mystring1="command1 D:\\The place\\The King\\ D:\\The place\\The Queen\\"
```

You could split the string at occurrences of `D:\\` and then removing spaces from the substrings will give you space free paths, e.g.

```
subs = mystring1.split('D:\\')
mystring2 = subs[0]
for s in subs[1:]: 
    mystring2 += ' D:\\' + s.replace(' ', '')
```

For example I applied this and got

```
>> mystring2
    'command1  D:\\Theplace\\TheKing\\  D:\\Theplace\\TheQueen\\'
```

If you just need to distinguish them use

```
def has_spaces(str1):
    subs = str1.split('D:\\')
    for s in subs[1:]: 
        if s.strip().count(' ') > 0:
        return True

>> has_spaces(mystring1)
    True
>> has_spaces(mystring2)
    False
```

to detect if any of the paths contain spaces. Cheers to Pengyu CHEN for pointing out the OP asked an easier question.

Comment: What he want is to distinguish those two strings, but not to transform one to another.